# How to add controls to a class inheriting from Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a custom control that I want to be available from Visual Studio's toolbox. The class looks like:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomPanel runat=server></{0}:CustomPanel>")]
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
}
```

So far, so good. The control is inheriting from a Panel and once added to the toolbox can be easily dragged and dropped on the aspx page. What I want to do now is add new controls to this panel such as labels and some basic HTML tags. I tried the following without success:

```
  [ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomPanel runat=server></{0}:CustomPanel>")]
  public class CustomPanel : Panel
  {
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
          Label name = new Label();
          name.Text = "Hello jdecuyer!";
          this.Controls.Add(name);
          base.OnInit(e);
     }
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide a location within the Panel for the label to appear.  Why don't you use Visual Studio to place the labels on the Panel, then add the Panel, with the labels already there?  You also are not adding the Label to the Panel, unless "this" is the Panel and not the Page, your incomplete code is hard to work that out.

Comment: Assuming that the `OnInit` sample is in `CustomPanel`, your code looks correct. What's not working?

Comment: Yes, "this" is the Panel, I just edited the code of my class again, sorry for not being clear enough. Although no error is thrown, no label is displayed inside the panel. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 1):

To make this considerably easier.  I would suggest:
1.) Create a UserControl then from the designer
2.) Add your custom panel class to that usercontrol
3.) Add your labels/links however you see fit.
4.) Add that UserControl to your Page

Ramhound is correct though, it seems you are not giving the label a location, though it should be slated to the top left automatically. And you are adding it to this as opposed to your panel.

Sorry I don't have much exp with asp.  Hope this was somewhat helpful.

Comment: Yes, creating a user control is a bit easier and I already managed to create one. However, they want me to add a compiled control to the Visual Studio's tool box. I will look into Yuriy's example to see how to add the label to my panel. Upvote and thanks!